# Ignore value conditionally within group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

Please consider the following.

***Background***

In a `data.frame` I have patient IDs (`id`), the day at which patients are admitted to a hospital (`day`), a code for the diagnostic activity they received that day (`code`), a price for that activity (`price`) and a frequency for that activity (`freq`).

Activities with `code` `b` and `c` are registered at the same time but mean more or less the same thing and should not be double counted.

---

***Problem***

What I want is: if `code` "b" and "c" are registered **for the same day**, `code` "b" should be ignored.

The example `data.frame` looks like this:

```
x <- data.frame(id = c(rep("a", 4), rep("b", 3)),
            day = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3),
            price = c(500, 10, 100, rep(10, 3), 100),
            code = c("a", "b", "c", rep("b", 3), "c"),
            freq = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 2))))

> x
  id day price code freq
1  a   1   500    a    1
2  a   1    10    b    1
3  a   1   100    c    1
4  a   2    10    b    1
5  b   1    10    b    1
6  b   2    10    b    2
7  b   3   100    c    2
```

So the costs for patient "a" for day 1 would be 600 and not 610 as I can compute with the following:

```
x %>% 
  group_by(id, day) %>% 
  summarise(res = sum(price * freq))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   id [?]
  id      day   res
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a        1.  610.
2 a        2.   10.
3 b        1.   10.
4 b        2.   20.
5 b        3.  200.
```

---

***Possible approaches***

Either I delete observation `code` "b" when "c" is present on that same day or I set `freq` of `code` "b" to 0 in case `code` "c" is present on the same day.

All my attempts with `ifelse` and `mutate` failed so far.

Every help is much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `filter` line to remove the offending `b` values like this...

```
x %>% 
  group_by(id, day) %>% 
  filter(!(code=="b" & "c" %in% code)) %>% 
  summarise(res = sum(price * freq))

  id      day   res
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a        1.  600.
2 a        2.   10.
3 b        1.   10.
4 b        2.   20.
5 b        3.  200.
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need but I don't understand why. Why is this statement only removing `b` and not `b` and `c`? Thanks!

Comment: It is removing the `b` rows in each `id,day` group (`code=="b"`) provided there is also a `c` in that group (`"c" %in% code`)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new column like this:

```
mutate(code_day = paste0(ifelse(code %in% c("b", "c"), "z", code), day)
```

Then all your Bs and Cs will become Zs (without losing the original code column that helps you tell them apart). You can then arrange by code descending and remove duplicate values in the code_day column:

```
arrange(desc(code)) %>% # Bs will come after Cs
distinct(code_day, .keep_all = TRUE)
```