# Remove duplicate rows conditionally within group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I know that there is a lot on removing duplicates out there but my problem seems different.

---

I have a `data.frame` similar to this:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
x <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3),
                date = as.Date(c("2016-04-24", "2016-04-24", "2016-04-24",
                                 "2016-04-24", "2016-04-24", "2016-04-28",
                                 "2016-04-28")),
                code = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a"))
x
#>   id       date code
#> 1  1 2016-04-24    a
#> 2  1 2016-04-24    b
#> 3  1 2016-04-24    b
#> 4  1 2016-04-24    a
#> 5  2 2016-04-24    a
#> 6  3 2016-04-28    a
#> 7  3 2016-04-28    a
```

I would like filter out all duplicates for `code` "a" but not "b". The expected output should look like this:

```r
x[c(1:3, 5:6), ]
#>   id       date code
#> 1  1 2016-04-24    a
#> 2  1 2016-04-24    b
#> 3  1 2016-04-24    b
#> 5  2 2016-04-24    a
#> 6  3 2016-04-28    a
```

---

I had a similar question here: [Ignore value conditionally within group_by in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50738942/ignore-value-conditionally-within-group-by-in-dplyr/50739095?noredirect=1#comment88489653_50739095) on which I base my following attempts. But these don't work and this is driving me nuts.

```r
x %>% group_by(id, date) %>% 
  filter(!(code == "a" & duplicated(code) == "a"))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#> # Groups:   id, date [3]
#>      id date       code 
#>   <dbl> <date>     <fct>
#> 1    1. 2016-04-24 a    
#> 2    1. 2016-04-24 b    
#> 3    1. 2016-04-24 b    
#> 4    1. 2016-04-24 a    
#> 5    2. 2016-04-24 a    
#> 6    3. 2016-04-28 a    
#> 7    3. 2016-04-28 a


x %>% group_by(id, date) %>% 
  filter(!(duplicated(code) == "a" & "a" %in% code))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#> # Groups:   id, date [3]
#>      id date       code 
#>   <dbl> <date>     <fct>
#> 1    1. 2016-04-24 a    
#> 2    1. 2016-04-24 b    
#> 3    1. 2016-04-24 b    
#> 4    1. 2016-04-24 a    
#> 5    2. 2016-04-24 a    
#> 6    3. 2016-04-28 a    
#> 7    3. 2016-04-28 a
```

Created on 2018-08-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

I guess the problem is with the `duplicated()` call that is not returning `TRUE` or `FALSE` but I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After grouping by 'id', 'date', get the logical vector where 'code' is 'a', use `duplicated` on that or where the 'code' is not 'a'

```
x %>% 
  group_by(id, date) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(code == "a") | code != 'a')
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   id, date [3]
#     id date       code 
#  <dbl> <date>     <fct>
#1     1 2016-04-24 a    
#2     1 2016-04-24 b    
#3     1 2016-04-24 b    
#4     2 2016-04-24 a    
#5     3 2016-04-28 a
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this works with `'a'` but not with `"a"`?

When I use

`x %>% 
  group_by(id, date) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(code == "a") | code != "a")` it ignores all codes `b`.

Comment: @Frederick. the quotes can be single or double.  It was just me typing

Comment: I have one follow-up question though: `filter(!duplicated(code == "a")` and `filter(!duplicated(code)` seem to do the same thing. Thus specifying `== "a"` in `duplicated()` seems redundant. Why is that?

Comment: @Frederick It could be a case with the example

Comment: @Frederick  For example check `v1 <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b'); !duplicated(v1 == 'a'); !duplicated(v1)`

Answer (score 2):

Another method using `slice`. Grouping by `id`, `date`, and `code`. If the group has any `a`'s in it (it should either be all `a`'s or all something else), take the first row, otherwise return the entire group:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% 
  group_by(id, date, code) %>% 
  slice(if(any(code == "a")) 1 else 1:n())
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   id, date, code [4]
     id date       code 
  <dbl> <date>     <fct>
1     1 2016-04-24 a    
2     1 2016-04-24 b    
3     1 2016-04-24 b    
4     2 2016-04-24 a    
5     3 2016-04-28 a
```

Answer (score 2):

With data.table, you can do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)

x[ code != "a" | !duplicated(x, by=c("id", "date", "code")) ]

   id       date code
1:  1 2016-04-24    a
2:  1 2016-04-24    b
3:  1 2016-04-24    b
4:  2 2016-04-24    a
5:  3 2016-04-28    a
```

This is similar to @akrun's answer, but no group-by is needed since `duplicated.data.table` has a `by=` argument. With base R (thanks to @Moody_Mudskipper), this can be translated to:

```
x[ code != "a" | !duplicated(x[c("id", "date", "code")]) ]
```

Comment: In base R that would be `x[x$code != "a" | !duplicated(x[c("id", "date", "code")]),]` or `subset(x,code != "a" | !duplicated(cbind(id, date, code)))`

Answer (score 0):

it is example without use of duplicated:

```
      data.frame(x%>%
      filter(code=="a")%>%
      group_by(id, date)%>%
      summarise(code=first(code)))%>%
      rbind(data.frame(x%>%filter(code=="b")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way in base R :

```
x$y <- cumsum(x$code=="b") * (x$code == "b")
unique(x)[-4]
#   id       date code
# 1  1 2016-04-24    a
# 2  1 2016-04-24    b
# 3  1 2016-04-24    b
# 5  2 2016-04-24    a
# 6  3 2016-04-28    a
```

(but I would probably rather use what i commented under Frank's answer)

With `tidyverse` I would do it like this :

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>% split(.$code) %>% map_at("a",distinct) %>% bind_rows 
#   id       date code
# 1  1 2016-04-24    a
# 2  2 2016-04-24    a
# 3  3 2016-04-28    a
# 4  1 2016-04-24    b
# 5  1 2016-04-24    b
```